# Assigning names incrementally

Tags: vba, excel, autofilter

I've filtered a range that now looks like this:

```
C         d       e
0609    Bogus   Bogus
2616    Bogus   Bogus
99904   99904   _ME Bogus
```

I want to go down the 3rd column and create a name using the value of the 1st column in the same row, incremented by 1.  So, 0609 will be Bogus1, 2616 will be Bogus2, etc. I will use those names in a different sheet to find the number of records with that code. I have this code so far:

```
 Dim b As Integer, b2 As Range, i As Integer
 For Each b2 In Range("e2:e" & LastCC).Areas

 If Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value) Then
            MsgBox "I'm not empty!"
        ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-2).Activate
        ActiveCell.Name = "BogusCC" & "1"
        i = i + 1
         Else
```

LastCC is defined earlier in the code not showing
                MsgBox ActiveCell.Value
            End If
      Next

First, the code is not incrementally naming the numbers in Column 1 as BogusCC1, then BogusCC2 etc.

Next it doesn't loop through the rows.

Apprciate the help in advance.

I edited the code to this:

```
 Dim b As Integer, b2 As Range, i As Integer
 i = 1
 Range("C1").Activate
 For Each b2 In Range("c2:c" & LastCC).Areas

 ' if cell not empty name company code
  Dim r As Range
  If Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value) Then
            MsgBox "I'm not empty!"


        For Each r In Range("c2:c" & LastCC)
            If Not IsEmpty(r) Then r.Offset(0, [-2]).Name = "BogusCC" & r.Row
        Next r
            i = i + 1
     Else
            MsgBox "Empty Cell"

  End If
  Next b2
End Sub
```

It almost works!!!.  It names the them all except the first one in the column.  Also changed the columns to A, B, and C

Comment: Question: what should happen (if it is possible) when in `C` the number e.g. `0609` occurs more than once? So e.g. twice the same resord of `0609`...`Bugus` and on some other row again `0609`...`Bugus`? Should `this` `Bogus` be counted only once or twice like `Bogus1` and `Bogus2`?

Comment: it wont happen more than once.  duplicates have been removed.

Comment: Then you can simply count each unique item of the 3rd column regardless of the first column, am I right? With other words the first column is not actually important.

Comment: no - the first column is important 
earlier in the code, the macro looks at all the numbers in the first column determines if they are valid.  the ones showing in this table are some kind of bogus.    Now that the bogus numbers are identified.  I want to go back and count the number of each bogus number.  The entire spreadsheet has over 18k rows.  Each bogus number could be in there up to 50 times.

Comment: So you count the number of each number in the first column (not the third one)? So the first `0609` would give you the `Bugus1` in fourth column,   second `0609` then `Bogus2` etc.? So the value in the fourth column would be something like [Text-In-Third-Column]&[Count-Of-Number-In-First-Column], OK?

Comment: Check edited answer, HTH.

Answer (score 2):

You need to cycle through the Areas collection and nest a cycle through each area's rows.

```
dim a as long, b as long, r as long

.autofilter stuff here
with .range(.cells(2, "C"), .cells(.rows.count, "C").end(xlup))
    with .resize(.rows.count, 3)
        if cbool(application.subtotal(103, .cells)) then
            with .specialcells(xlcellstypevisible)
                for a = 1 to .areas.count
                    with .areas(a)
                        for r=1 to .rows.count
                            b=b+1
                            .cells(r, 3) = format(b, "\b\o\g\u\s0")  
                        next r
                    end with
                next a
            end with
        end with
    end with
for each a
```

Comment: Possibly relevant: [Flattening Arrow Code](https://blog.codinghorror.com/flattening-arrow-code/), by Jeff Atwood :-)

Answer (score 1):

Check the LastCC - I tested it on a static range e.g. (E2:E10) and works fine.

```
Dim r As Range

For Each r In Range("e2:e" & LastCC)
    If Not IsEmpty(r) Then r.Offset(0, [-2]).Name = "BogusCC" & r.Row
Next r
```

Comment: @ aoswald "It names them all except the first one in the column."  Range("e1:e" & LastCC) perhaps?

Comment: yes @Kostas - changed e2 to e1 and it worked - thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly what is needed is just to count unique values in the first column and add the value of last column with number of actual occurrence to column after this one. Here an example which uses `Dictionary` to count this occurrences.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Main()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:C11")
    WriteNames rng
End Sub

Public Sub WriteNames(rng As Range)
    Dim nms As Object
    Set nms = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Dim r As Range
    Dim nm As String
    For Each r In rng.Rows
        nm = Trim(r.Cells(1).Value)
        If nms.Exists(nm) Then
            nms.Item(nm) = nms.Item(nm) + 1
        Else
            nms.Add nm, 1
        End If
        r.Cells(r.Cells.Count).Offset(0, 1).Value = r.Cells(r.Cells.Count) & nms.Item(nm)
    Next r
End Sub
```